# CMS to manage Mobile website and main website

Tags: html, css, wordpress, content-management-system

Can someone shed some light onto the area of content management for a website that has a mobile version as well as a main version.

How do you manage these? Do you create 2 versions of the site or do you use conditional selection if the site is mobile, then show XYZ?

Lloyds has the following, mobile and main websites:

As you can see not all of the assets are included on the mobile versiuon.

mobile:
[image]

Main website:
[image]

Comment: use html5 `data-role` to display contents on desktop or mobile

Comment: `Media-queries` are your best friend.

Answer (score 1):

Content should be separated from layout/design. That is the main goal of a CMS.

This means that the CMS will be the same for both versions, since the content will be the same. In order to provide a different mobile version you should look into using a [responsive WordPress template](https://theme.wordpress.com/themes/features/responsive-layout/), or design one yourself.

Alternatively there are WordPress plugins that will serve a completely different template if the user is browsing from a mobile browser. (Check out [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mobile-edition/) for example)

Answer (score 1):

If you use any CMS (Joomla, Wordpress and others) all have a good supports for every devices from big monitor to mobile devices. So you no need to worry about the layout and only have to work on content part. Using `@media queries' we can target any devices and monitors; and layout will be change accordingly. For example check the below CSS Code; Background color will change accordingly devices.

```
@media (max-width: 400px) { /*for Mobile*/
  html { background: red; }
}
@media (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 800px) { /*For Tablets*/
  html { background: green; }
}
@media (min-width: 801px) { /*For Desktop Monitors*/
  html { background: blue; }
}
```

As you mentioned about the website; the main purpose is to achieve the main goal. And there goal is to provide their users to get access their account at anytime. And its solve their goals. and they are just showing only thing which have more impact to user goals.

Comment: Is this answer helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

You need a CMS that can function as a mobile CMS so that you can control your content on your website and on mobile. ButterCMS is a headless CMS that can achieve this and here is a blog post about how you can create your own [mobile CMS](https://buttercms.com/blog/a-complete-guide-to-managing-content-with-a-mobile-cms) solution using ButterCMS and Flutter by Google.